# Inserting let to bind a local variable

Tags: ocaml, metaprogramming, metaocaml

I'm working through Oleg Kiselyov's tutorial *Reconciling Abstraction with High Performance: A MetaOCaml approach*. One exercise (exercise 23) asks for a let-insertion to bind an array index access to a local variable. 
The function of question is `vmult_ca`, which generates code for multiplying arrays of complex numbers:

```
let vmult_ca : 
    (float_complex array -> float_complex array -> float_complex array -> unit)
    code =
 .<fun vout v1 v2 ->
    let n = Array.length vout in  
                                      (* vector representations *)
  .~(let vout = OVec (.<n>., fun i v -> 
       .<vout.(.~i) <- .~(of_code_complex v)>.) in
     let v1   = Vec  (.<n>., fun i -> 
       of_complex_code .<v1.(.~i)>.) in
     let v2   = Vec  (.<n>., fun i -> 
       of_complex_code .<v2.(.~i)>.) in
     let module V = VMULT(FloatCodeComplex)(VecDyn) in
     V.vmult vout v1 v2)
  >.
;;
```

Where `vout` is the output vector that store the result. 
`Vec (n, fun i -> v)` is an abstract vector where `n` is the length and `fun i -> v` maps each index to a value. 
`OVec (n, fun i v -> body)` is an abstract "output vector" where `n` is the length and `fun i v -> body` runs on each index `i` and the associated output element `v` at `i`. 
`of_complex_code` converts a `complex code` value to a `code complex` value, e.g. `.<{real=1.0, imag=0.0}>.` to `{real=.<1.0>., imag=.<0.0>.}`. 
The module `VMULT` defines (point-wise) vector multiplication (see the code [here](http://okmij.org/ftp/meta-programming/tutorial/complex.ml) for details).

When run, `vmult_ca` generates the following code:

```
val vmult_ca :
  (float_complex array -> float_complex array -> float_complex array -> unit)
  code = .<
  fun vout_4  ->
    fun v1_5  ->
      fun v2_6  ->
        let n_7 = Array.length vout_4  in
        for i_8 = 0 to n_7 - 1 do
          vout_4.(i_8) <-
            {
              Cmplx.im =
                (((v1_5.(i_8)).Cmplx.re *. (v2_6.(i_8)).Cmplx.im) +.
                   ((v1_5.(i_8)).Cmplx.im *. (v2_6.(i_8)).Cmplx.re));
              Cmplx.re =
                (((v1_5.(i_8)).Cmplx.re *. (v2_6.(i_8)).Cmplx.re) -.
                   ((v1_5.(i_8)).Cmplx.im *. (v2_6.(i_8)).Cmplx.im))
            }
        done>.
```

Note `v1_5.(i_8)` is repeated 4 times. The challenge is to insert a `let` somewhere in `vmult_ca` to bind `v1_5.(i_8)` to a local variable to avoid the repetition. I was able to "cheat" by simply calling `genlet` on `.<v1.(~i)>.`, but I have no clue where to insert the `let` without `genlet`; any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let-insertion is [a primitive operation](http://okmij.org/ftp/ML/MetaOCaml.html#genlet) in BER, that automatically binds the passed code to a freshly generated variable.

Here is a working example, suppose you have the code that returns a square of an array element,

```
let power_elt xs i = xs.(i) * xs.(i)
```

and we want to generate an optimized code that has only one array access

```
let power_elt xs i = let x = xs.(i) in x*x
```

In the MetaOCaml style we can use `genlet` for that

```
let power_elt xs i =
  let x = genlet .<xs.(i)>. in 
  .<.~x * .~x>.
```

The generated code for

```
 let t = power_elt [|1;2;3|] 1;;
```

will be

```
 val t : int code = .<let lv_8 = Stdlib.Array.get (* CSP xs *) 1 in lv_8 * lv_8>.
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up "cheating" by calling `genlet` on `.<v1.(.~i)>.` and `.<v2.(.~i)>.`. However, I think the point of the exercise is to insert the let without using `genlet`. But if `genlet` "just works", perhaps I don't need to know how to manually insert let. Would you say `genlet` "just works"?